# Input type <select> with search textbox in ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to implement this kind of `<select>` in ASP.NET.

What I want is to have a search text box like here when I click the `<select>` like in this [link](http://themes.stammtec.de/?theme=peach) just put any login details.

I have this code working in PHP with jQuery and CSS. But I don't know where or how can I implement this in ASP.NET. I tried copying the codes but it didn't work for dynamic contents.

**Update:**

Here's the html code without script whatsoever:

```
<select name="blogpost-category" id="blogpost-category" class="required chzn-done"> 
   <option></option>
   <option>Lorem Ipsum</option>
   <option>Consetetur Sadipscing</option> 
   <option>Eirmod Tempor</option>
</select>
```

Please take note that the `name`, `id` and `class` in ASP.NET can be declared or include in code behind and the `ID`'s are system generated. What I'm trying to say is that when I set the value of ID in C# like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" />
```

OR

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="blogpost-category" runat="server" />
```

and binding the data using this C# script:

```
    Dictionary<string,string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    DataTable dt = FillData(SQL_SELECT);

    dict.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
    dict.Add(def.ADDNEW, def.ADDNEW);

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        dict.Add(dr.ItemArray[def.ID].ToString(), dr.ItemArray[def.NAME].ToString());
    }//foreach

    ddlCategory.DataSource = dict;
    ddlCategory.DataValueField = def.KEY;
    ddlCategory.DataTextField = def.VALUE;
    ddlCategory.DataBind();
```

the result `ID` for both would be:

`ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlCategory` and `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_blogpost-category` repectively.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you meaning the 'Category' drop down in the page after logging in? What have you tried and what specifically can't you get to work?  Please note that if you look at the markup it's not a <select> but a <div> which shows another <div>

Comment: You could do the auto-complete magic in javascript. jQuery has a lot of support for that.

Comment: The problem here is that when I bought the theme with extended license to codes, I can't really determine the exact dependencies or the script that used in the html file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can make that with ASP.NET also. Firstly you need to get the things with "Web User Controls" in ASP.NET and then continue with that.. :)

Happy coding.. :)

Comment: I don't understand, can you please elaborate? Please check my update.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:DropDownList id="blogpost-category" runat="server"
     DataSource="<% databindingexpression %>"
     DataTextField="Model.description"
     DataValueField="Model.id"
     AutoPostBack="True|False">

     <asp:ListItem value="value" selected="True|False">
          Text
     </asp:ListItem>

 </asp:DropDownList>
```

Have you tried it like this, bind the datasource (the collection that needs to be displayed, datatextfield is the text that will be displayed, datavaluefield the id